# Data Factory Release Pipeline Issues

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-data-factory

**The Goal**

The goal is to use a Release Pipeline inside Azure DevOps to copy the contents of a DEV ADF environment to a PROD ADF environment. This should work by monitoring the adf_publish branch for changes and publishing the ARM template files to the PROD ADF environment.

**The Issue**

Although the pipeline reports a success, when I check the PROD environment it's empty still.

[Pipeline Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnIml.png)

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKm9S.png)

**Environment Structure**

The two ADF environments, DEV and PROD, are in the same resource group in the Azure Portal and are backed up to seperate repos: ADFV2-DEV and ADFV2-PRD respectively. Each has a master branch.

**What I've Tried**

When I removed PROD from source control, meaning all changes are saved inside ADF with no branching/git/etc. then the release pipeline works as expected. As such, I thought maybe the issue was permissions inside Azure DevOps.

I tried giving blanket "Allow" permissions to every group/user for every permission to see if that was where the issue lay, however there was no change in result.

[Branch Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHebv.png)

As such, I *think* the issue lies with the fact that the PROD ADF environment is in an Azure Git Repo, however I can't narrow down what's causing the issue.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. There's somewhat of a need to have both ADF environments backed up in source control.

**Note**

This is my first stackoverflow question so I apologize in advance for any glaring errors or misteps. Please let me know if I've crossed any lines and I'll gladly fix/expand/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading more documentation, it seems the issue lies with git integration in the PROD environment. In [this microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment) the following is stated:

> Git Integration. You're only required to configure your Development data factory with Git integration. Changes to Test and Production are deployed via CI/CD, and don't need Git integration.

Removing git integration from the PROD environment appears to resolve the issue. I was hoping this could be fixed without removing git, however it appears to not be needed.